# Hover over one div triggers other div hovers inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok working on something and can't seem to figure it out have tried a few different things but nothing seems to solve it. So here is the link to what I'm doing...

http://modocom.ca/logo/

Now what I'm trying to do is have the outer div when you rollover it, it animates all the inner divs at once. Also trying to achieve so can click on the outer div to go to a link.

Here is the HTML...

```
<div>
<div class="hi-icon-wrap hi-icon-effect-5 hi-icon-effect-5d transition">
        <a href="#" class="hi-icon hi-icon-modo-m transition">modo</a>
</div>
<div class="hi-icon-wrap hi-icon-effect-6 hi-icon-effect-5d transition">
        <a href="#" class="hi-icon hi-icon-modo-o transition">modo</a>
</div>    
<div class="hi-icon-wrap hi-icon-effect-5 hi-icon-effect-5d transition">
        <a href="#" class="hi-icon hi-icon-modo-d transition">modo</a>
</div>
<div class="hi-icon-wrap hi-icon-effect-6 hi-icon-effect-5d transition">
        <a href="#" class="hi-icon hi-icon-modo-star transition">modo</a>
</div>
```

Some of the CSS for the inner hovers...

```
    .hi-icon-effect-5 .hi-icon {
    border-top: 5px solid #C30;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.hi-icon-effect-6 .hi-icon {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.hi-icon-effect-5 .hi-icon:after {
    display: none;
}

.hi-icon-effect-6 .hi-icon:after {
    display: none;
}

.hi-icon-effect-7 .hi-icon:after {
    display: none;
}

.no-touch .hi-icon-effect-5 .hi-icon:hover {
    background: #C30;
    color: #FFF; /* Hover Icon */
}

.no-touch .hi-icon-effect-6 .hi-icon:hover {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF; /* Hover Icon */
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: All i can see here is a logo. I don't understand what's your problem

Comment: could you add your css for this?

Comment: Hi Guys,

Thanks sorry for not explaining better when you rollover I want all it to animate not just one of the letters. So trying to make the outside div when you hover over it all the inner divs animate at once and can click on the outside div. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: For a simple logo effect, why don't you just use two images and add id to the outer div. When hovered, change from one to another? Unless each letter goes to a different page??

Comment: No each letter won't go to a separate page, I suppose I could just use a simple image approach but was just trying to spice it up a little more but if that is what should be doing then may need to change to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a class to your main div... in this case lets say you add `class=maindiv' to the containing div.

Then in your css use this:

```
.maindiv:hover .no-touch .hi-icon-effect-5 .hi-icon {
    background: #C30;
    color: #FFF; /* Hover Icon */
}

.maindiv:hover .no-touch .hi-icon-effect-6 .hi-icon {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF; /* Hover Icon */
}
```

instead of the effects applying when you hover over the `.hi-icon` the effects apply when you hover over the `.maindiv`

**UPDATE**

add this to your css instead of the above:

```
.maindiv:hover .hi-icon-effect-5 .hi-icon{
    background: #C30;
    color: #FFF; /* Hover Icon */
}

.maindiv:hover .hi-icon-effect-6 .hi-icon {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF; /* Hover Icon */
}
```

Comment: Hello JCBigger,

Thanks for that unfortunately it didnt work. The hover effect doesn't seem to work at all now. This is something I encountered before as well thought it would work but doesnt seem too

Comment: Im about to look into it.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated :) Trying to make it so the whole main div links as well but doesn't seem to work was thinking if I just have each letter link it may work that way.

Comment: Hey JCBigger, I got it linking to different page. Had to link each letter but it does work. So just the hover effect on the main div to animate all the other divs, so getting closer.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks so much, not sure if its possible to slide the background down like its sliding down from the top borders instead of fading in? Or is that more difficult to do? Also is it possible to time each of the boxes down so say the first then second one comes down then third and fourth like just almost right after each other or that pushing it lol just trying to do something a bit different.

Comment: Im sure there is probably a way to do that... Not with css, i dont think. But im not really to sure how I would go about that. Glad this helped though.

Answer (score 0):

I might be horribly off track, but could you use `.addClass` to each of those divs when you hover over the main div?

Something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/63J27/2/) (I didnt add a class, i just used `.animate` to get my point accross)

```
$( "#Activate" ).mouseover(function() {

$("#Activate > .hi-icon-wrap").each(function (index) {
    $(this).delay(index * 500).animate({
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 500);
});
  });

  $( "#Activate" ).mouseout(function() {
    $(".hi-icon-wrap").animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
});
```

Apologies if this is nothing at all what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi Mike,

Not really what I was looking for I don't believe. But thank you replying much appreciated. I think JCBigger is closing in onto a solution that will work. 

Many Thanks

Comment: Okay sure :) I often misread questions .. haha .. sorry about that!